# Digital Signature using CAPICOM needs to be 1024 bits long

Tags: c#, .net, digital-signature, capicom

We are trying to sign documents using RSA-SHA1 hash. We have tried using the Crypt32 lib and we are getting signature (DS) length of 1024 bits (172 bytes after BASE-64) which is proper.
When we try to do the same with CAPICOM, the length comes to be 2292 bytes (BASE-64). How can we have DS length of 172 while using CAPICOM?

Answer (score 0):

it could be one of two things.  because capicom treats the data as unicode, or because capicom ds includes the signer certificate.